# Redirect all subdirectories of an specific domain to index of that same domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Im trying to redirect all the subdirectories of an specific domain "domain.net/subdir/" to "domain.net/index.html" i want it to be for this specific domain because im working with multiple domains and i do not want it to redirect the others.

How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want redirect one subdirectory or all subdirectory

Comment: all subdirectories of that particular domain